# buscar por ID para cada item da lista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

tenho uma classe que se chama atendimento.
nela eu tenho os seguintes atributos:

```
public class Atendimento
{

    public Guid AtendimentoId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ResponsavelPorAtender { get; set; }
    public Guid? AdmQueAutorizou { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public Guid IdUsuario { get; set; }

}
```

o atributo   `public Guid? ResponsavelPorAtender` e `public Guid? AdmQueAutorizou` são os usuáros tbm, da mesma forma que o  `public Guid IdUsuario`
quando eu faço uma consulta, que busca todos os atendimentos, como eu faço para atribuir o nome do usuario, ao por exemplo:`public Guid? ResponsavelPorAtender`
quanto ao `public Guid IdUsuario` eu apenas uso o include.

```
public IEnumerable<Atendimento> ObterTodos()
{
  return Db.AtendimentosDb.Include("Usuario");
}
```

e mostro no meu Index Asssim:

```
<table 
    <thead style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>
         Aberto Por:
        </th>
        <th>
        Fechado Por:
        </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
          {

           <tr>
             <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Usuario.Nome)
               </td>
               <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResponsavelPorAtender )
                </td>
            </tr>
           }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

o Reponsavel por atender é o ID do usuario que antendeu.
como eu faço para cada item desse lista buscar o usuário?

Classe Usuario:

```
public class Usuario
    {

        public Guid UsuarioId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Cpf { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
        public TipoDeUsuario TipoDeUsuario { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Como está seu relacionamento? Poderia adicionar sua classe `Usuario`?

Comment: Editei, e coloquei a classe usuario

Answer (score 3):

Bem, primeiramente deve-se fazer o mapeamento das suas entidades. Da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Atendimento
{
    public Guid AtendimentoId { get; set; }

    public Guid? ResponsavelPorAtender { get; set; }

    public Guid? AdmQueAutorizou { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public Guid IdUsuario { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario{ get; set;} // Aqui foi criado uma entidade de navegação 
}
```

E `Usuario` ter relacionado a lista de atendimentos:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public Guid UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public TipoDeUsuario TipoDeUsuario { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Atendimento> Atendimentos { get; set; } // Aqui foi criado uma entidade de navegação para uma lista de atendimento
}
```

Sendo assim, o `EntityFramework` já conhece que esses dados estão relacionados, e fazendo a consulta utilizando o `Include` é convertido para uma consulta SQL trazendo os registros corretamente

```
public IEnumerable<Atendimento> ObterTodos()
{
  return Db.AtendimentosDb
           .Include(Atd => Atd.Usuario)
           .ToList();
}
```